# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority - logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder

I created a logstash-forwarder crt and key on server with wild card as Common Name and on copying the certificate on forwarder I am getting the message

```
Failed to tls handshake with 123.123.123.123 x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Logstash Server 1.5.3
Logstash Forwarder 0.4.0

Comment: Please help me out as I am trying to solve for the multiple logstash servers and single forwarder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to check your certificate carefully.

Have you specified a plain wildcard CN? `*` does not match `.` so perhaps it won't match your domain. A proper wildcard CN should be something like `*.example.com`.

Have you tried to verify your certificate with another software? e.g. a webserver? I suppose this is not a logstash issue.

Comment: Yes, I was not mentioning properly the CA certificate in ssl ca in logstash-forwarder.conf which I used to sign the crt.